# Kubelet certificate expired but work nodes working fine, when we will see the issue

Tags: kubernetes, kubelet

In my `v1.23.1` test cluster I see worker node certificate expired some time ago. but worker node still taking the workload and in `Ready` status.

How this certificate is getting used, when we will see the issue with expired certificate?

```
# curl -v https://localhost:10250  -k 2>&1 |grep 'expire date'
*  expire date: Oct  4 18:02:14 2021 GMT


# openssl x509 -text -noout -in /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet.crt |grep -A2 'Validity'
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct  4 18:02:14 2020 GMT
            Not After : Oct  4 18:02:14 2021 GMT
```

**Update 1:**
Cluster is running on-perm with `CentOS Stream 8` OS , build with `kubeadm` tool. I was able to schedule the workload on all the worker nodes. created nginx deployment and scaled it 50 pods, I can see nginx PODs on all the worker nodes.

Also I can reboot the work nodes with-out any issue.

Update 2:

```
kubeadm certs check-expiration
[check-expiration] Reading configuration from the cluster...
[check-expiration] FYI: You can look at this config file with 'kubectl -n kube-system get cm kubeadm-config -o yaml'
W0303 11:17:18.261639  698383 utils.go:69] The recommended value for "resolvConf" in "KubeletConfiguration" is: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf; the provided value is: /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

CERTIFICATE                EXPIRES                  RESIDUAL TIME   CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY   EXTERNALLY MANAGED
admin.conf                 Jan 16, 2023 16:15 UTC   318d            ca                      no
apiserver                  Jan 16, 2023 16:15 UTC   318d            ca                      no
apiserver-kubelet-client   Jan 16, 2023 16:15 UTC   318d            ca                      no
controller-manager.conf    Jan 16, 2023 16:15 UTC   318d            ca                      no
front-proxy-client         Jan 16, 2023 16:15 UTC   318d            front-proxy-ca          no
scheduler.conf             Jan 16, 2023 16:15 UTC   318d            ca                      no

CERTIFICATE AUTHORITY   EXPIRES                  RESIDUAL TIME   EXTERNALLY MANAGED
ca                      Oct 02, 2030 18:44 UTC   8y              no
front-proxy-ca          Oct 02, 2030 18:44 UTC   8y              no
```

Thanks

**Update 3**

```
# kubectl get nodes  
NAME        STATUS   ROLES                  AGE    VERSION
server10   Ready    control-plane,master   519d   v1.23.1
server11   Ready    control-plane,master   519d   v1.23.1
server12   Ready    control-plane,master   519d   v1.23.1
server13   Ready    <none>                 519d   v1.23.1
server14   Ready    <none>                 519d   v1.23.1
server15   Ready    <none>                 516d   v1.23.1
server16   Ready    <none>                 516d   v1.23.1
server17   Ready    <none>                 516d   v1.23.1
server18   Ready    <none>                 516d   v1.23.1


# kubectl get pods -o wide   
nginx-dev-8677c757d4-4k9xp                 1/1     Running     0             4d12h   10.203.53.19    server17   <none>           <none>
nginx-dev-8677c757d4-6lbc6                 1/1     Running     0             4d12h   10.203.89.120   server14   <none>           <none>
nginx-dev-8677c757d4-ksckf                 1/1     Running     0             4d12h   10.203.124.4    server16   <none>           <none>
nginx-dev-8677c757d4-lrz9h                 1/1     Running     0             4d12h   10.203.124.41   server16   <none>           <none>
nginx-dev-8677c757d4-tllx9                 1/1     Running     0             4d12h   10.203.151.70   server11   <none>           <none>

# grep client /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf
    client-certificate: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem
    client-key: /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-current.pem

# ls -ltr /var/lib/kubelet/pki
total 16
-rw------- 1 root root 1679 Oct  4  2020 kubelet.key
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2258 Oct  4  2020 kubelet.crt
-rw------- 1 root root 1114 Oct  4  2020 kubelet-client-2020-10-04-14-50-21.pem
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root   59 Jul  6  2021 kubelet-client-current.pem -> /var/lib/kubelet/pki/kubelet-client-2021-07-06-01-44-10.pem
-rw------- 1 root root 1114 Jul  6  2021 kubelet-client-2021-07-06-01-44-10.pem
```

Comment: Can you add more details about your Kubernetes cluster - in cloud, on VM, minikube, etc? Are you able to schedule pods on this node or you just see `Ready` status without making any operations?

Comment: What about the output for `kubeadm certs check-expiration`? Do you have up-to-date time in your cluster?

Comment: @AndrewSkorkin  Yes, added the output of the command

Comment: It seems you not used standard kubeadm configuration, when bootstrapping the cluster. If so, can you provide details on additional configuration? Please provide next information:

`kubectl get nodes` - to see if all nodes are ready.
`kubectl get pods -o wide` - to see if all pods are scheduled to different nodes.


Check from where kubeadm is reading data by. Execute: 
`kubeadm certs check-expiration -v6 | grep "Config loaded"`
Check directory for - client-certificate of `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf` file.
What is current date in the system?

Comment: I setup this cluster with `kubeadm`  command. for `check-expiration` command I can see `Config loaded from file:  /etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf` line.  I can see nginx pod created on all the worker nodes when I scale the deployment to 50.  all these server time is current synced with ntp server.

Comment: Can you add requested outputs to the question - `kubectl get nodes` , `kubectl get pods -o wide` ? Also, please provide which directory is using for `client-certificate` in `/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf` file?

Comment: added more output

Comment: Thanks for the update. I am interested in the following information: - Can you provide current kubelet configuration on particular node?
- Can you verify if using curl command against kubelet server and openssl command against kubelet.crt we have the same values in server certificate for "Issuer" and "subject"?
- Have you used a custom --cert-dir directory in kubelet config while bootstrapping worker node?

Comment: looks like other people also had same kind of issue: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubeadm/issues/2186, still its not clear how this certs are getting used.

Comment: From the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/architecture/control-plane-node-communication/#control-plane-to-node) for connection from apiserver to kubelet: "These connections terminate at the kubelet's HTTPS endpoint. By default, the apiserver does not verify the kubelet's serving certificate, which makes the connection subject to man-in-the-middle attacks and unsafe to run over untrusted and/or public networks"

Comment: From the command `kubeadm certs check-expiration` you can see that kubelet.conf is not presented in the output. Also from the [documentation](
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/kubeadm/kubeadm-certs/#check-certificate-expiration): "Note: kubelet.conf is not included in the list above because kubeadm configures kubelet for automatic certificate renewal with rotatable certificates under /var/lib/kubelet/pki. To repair an expired kubelet client certificate see Kubelet client certificate rotation fails." But this true for kubelet client cert, not kubelet server certificates.

Comment: As stated above, kubelet.conf is not included in the preflight checks. Also, kubelet.conf contains links to the valid "CLIENT" kubelet certificate and key, not a "SERVER" kubelet certificate and key.
 
You can update kubelet.crt and kubelet.key in the next way (for one of the nodes). 1. Drain workload from particular node to the other one using `kubectl drain` command. 2. Backup kubelet.crt, kubelet.key. 3. Delete kubelet.crt. kubelet.key, located in /var/lib/kubelet/pki 4. Restart kubelet 5. Verify the data for kubelet.crt using `openssl` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those kubelet certificates is called kubelet-serving certificates. They are used when Kubelet acts as a "server" instead of a "client".
For example, kubelet provides metrics to metrics server. So when metrics-server was enabled to use secure-tls, and in case that those certificate are expired, the metrics-server would not have a proper connection to Kubelet to get the metrics. In case you are using K8s Dashboard, the Dashboard will not able to show CPU and memory consumption in the page. That's the time when you see the issue from those expired certificates.

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/kubelet-tls-bootstrapping/#client-and-serving-certificates

Those certificate will not auto-rotate when expiring. They are not also able to be rotated with "kubeadm certificate renew". To renew those certificate, you will need to add "serverTLSBootstrap: true" in your cluster config. With this, when the serving certificate expired, kubelet will send a CSR request to K8s cluster, from the cluster, you can use "kubectl certificate approve" to renew them.